# Saving dates in MySQL stores incorrectly as "0000-00-00"

Tags: php, mysql

This is my HTML code:

```
        <p>Leave duration:<input type = "date" name="leave_start"/>to
                          <input type = "date" name="leave_end"/></p>
```

Below is my SQL code:

```
$sql = ("INSERT INTO  `leave` (  `Leave_Start` ,  `Leave_End` ) 
                    VALUES({$_POST["leave_start"]},{$_POST["leave_end"]}')");
```

Comment: Before you do anything else, fix the gaping SQL injection vulnerability in your code.

Comment: Try to var_dump the query that is beeing inserted. You should also take care of escaping data or change to prepared statements, atm you're wide open for sql injections

Comment: I second @JimL: use [prepared statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ignoring the nasty [SQL injection attack](http://bobby-tables.com) holes in your code, you have to use MySQL's native date-as-string format when doing date-related operations in the DB, e.g. `yyyy-mm-dd`, or `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss` for date+time. If you try to insert anything else, MySQL will **TRY** to interpret it to a date, but won't try too hard. Any dates that can't be properly interpreted will simply show up as your `0000-00-00` version.

That means

```
... VALUES ('2013-08-01', '2013-08-31');
```

will work, but something like

```
... VALUES ('Aug 01/2013', '31st August 2013')
```

will utterly fail.